# On Oracle Linux 6, I am trying to start the postgresql service and it's failing with 'runuser: /bin/bash:/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory'

Tags: linux, bash, root, su, oracle-linux

Everything was working fine until this morning.  The postgresql service has stopped and I can't start it.

When I run the command `sudo service postgresql start`, I get a [FAILED] message.  Then, I go to the /var/lib/pgsql/pgstartup.log file, and I see the following error message:

```
runuser: /bin/bash:/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
```

Then I tried to su to root, which I have been able to do in the past, but I get the same error message.  Then I tried to su to the user postgres, and I get the same error message.

The files do exist, I checked them both (/bin/bash and /sbin/nologin).

NOTE - I was able to resolve the error by typing the following command - `sudo chsh root -s $SHELL`.  This actually allowed me to start the postgresql server after su'ing to root.  I guess my question now is - Does anyone know what would cause this situation?  Should I be concerned that my system is compromised security-wise?

Comment: Presumably someone edited the password database and changed the user's login shell to `/bin/bash:/sbin/nologin`

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, your root user's login shell was set to the literal value `/bin/bash:/sbin/nologin`.  When running things as root through `sudo` and when the root login shell was needed, the system would be trying to execute the literal command `/bin/bash:/sbin/nologin`, which for obvious reasons does not exist. It does not matter that `/bin/bash` and `/sbin/nologin` exists separately.

After your fix with `chsh`, you most likely want to check the root login shell to make sure that it is in fact `/bin/bash` (the default login shell on Oracle Linux). You should be able to do that by simply checking the entry returned by

```
getent passwd root
```

There should be seven `:`-delimited fields, and the last should say `/bin/bash`.